# Is a good practice to send ajax post every 1 second to check database modifications?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to check if there's some modification in a specific status in database. To do it real time, I want to send an Ajax Post every 1 second to check in the MySQL database if has some modification.

But I have doubts about the performance. The page will probably stay open for hours. Then I don't know if is a good idea to do, every second, a "SELECT QUERY" in database.

Someone knows if there's some problem stay a page opened for hours, sending ajax post every second, checking MySQL database (Select Query) and changing the page with the result (when status modified)?

PS: (1) There's not possible to use websocket. (2) I'm using PHP and MySQL. (3) The server is Windows running XAMPP.

The code is (it works):

```
function status_check(){
    var AJAX_URL = $('#AJAX_URL').val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var body = $('body');
        var ss = body.attr('data-step');
        var formData = {
            ss: ss,
            a: 'cn'
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: AJAX_URL,
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                // change the HTML with the returned data if has modification
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, thrown){
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });

        status_check();
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  status_check();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a good practice or not, but I'm sure that you should be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

This practice is called short polling which is resource intense in client requests and database queries.

As you already mentioned an ideal solution might be websockets but with only PHP this is out of question.

An alternative approach could be long polling. With long polling a client-server connection is kept open until a response is available. Which on the server could look somewhat like that.

```
do {
    $newData = getNewData();
    if($newData) {
        echo $newData;
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
} while (!$newData);
```